# Dynamically create accessible UILabels in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to dynamically create UILabels for each letter in a word in objective-c. As you can see, I'm passing in the number of letters that will be used for the word and I need to fill in the commented section below:

```
-(void)createWordLabels:(int)numberOfLetters
{
    //create a set of word labels
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++)
    {
        //create a set of labels for each of the letters -> connect them to variables
    }
}
```

The labels need to be accessible to change. If I want to change one letter from A -> B, then I would like to be able to do that dynamically. Any help would be appreciated here.

Right now here's what I have, however, I'd like to be able to center the group of labels in the middle of the screen:

```
    -(void)createWordLabels:(int)wordSize
{
    int width = 0;
    //create a set of word labels
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < wordSize; i++)
    {
        //TO DO: create a set of labels for each of the letters -> connect them to variables
        UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20 + width, 150, 30, 50)];
        [newLabel setText:@"-"];
        newLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [self.view addSubview:newLabel];
        [newLabel release];
        width += 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to make an array instance var of UILabels?

Comment: when do you call this method? how many time this method is being called? Is it called once and then after you just change the letters?

Comment: @Jorge @Ravin see above edits for some code that I've managed to write. The problem is how to position these elements and center them now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a tag value for each UILabels

e.g.

```
#define LABEL_TAG 1000

-(void)createWordLabels:(int)numberOfLetters
{
    //create a set of word labels
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++)
    {
        //create a set of labels for each of the letters -> connect them to variables
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel......
        [label setTag:LABEL_TAG+i];
        [self addSubview:label];
        ......
    }
}
```

Then to accessed a label a position 10 for example

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[self viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG+10];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
//For printing the text using for loop we change the cordinates every time for example see the "y=(i*20) like this we change x also so every time when loop run,the statement will print in different location"   

//This is use for adding dynamic label and also the last line must be written in the same scope. 

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,(i*40), 100, 100)];

    //titleLabel = titleLabel;
    //[titleLabel release];

    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:20];
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    titleLabel.text = @"mihir patel";

//Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of label
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300,400);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [@"mihir" sizeWithFont:titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:titleLabel.lineBreakMode];
//Adjust the label the the new height
    CGRect newFrame = titleLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    titleLabel.frame = newFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:titleLabel];

    }


}
```